# How to conditional left shift based on null values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, coalesce, fillna, null-coalescing-operator

I have a data frame like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,np.nan,5],"B":[np.nan,10,np.nan], "C":[2,3,np.nan]})
     A     B   C
0    1   NaN   5
1   NaN  10   NaN
2    2    3   NaN
```

I want to left shift all the values to occupy the nulls. Desired output:

```
     A     B   C 
0    1     5  NaN
1   10   NaN  NaN
2    2    3   NaN
```

I tried doing this using a series of `df['A'].fillna(df['B'].fillna(df['C'])` but in my actual data there are more than 100 columns. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us do

```
out = df.T.apply(lambda x : sorted(x,key=pd.isnull)).T
Out[41]: 
      A    B   C
0   1.0  5.0 NaN
1  10.0  NaN NaN
2   2.0  3.0 NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

I also figured out another way to do this without the sort:

```
def shift_null(arr):
  return [x for x in arr if x == x] + [np.nan for x in arr if x != x]

out = df.T.apply(lambda arr: shift_null(arr)).T
```

This was faster for big dataframes.